# Incorporating Measurements of Item Uncertainty into Bayesian Models

Tags: regression, bayesian, interaction

Imagine I have a dataset of four variables:

1. Age (Continuous)
2. Gender (M/F)
3. Vote for Incumbent (Yes/No)
4. Like Leader (Yes/No)

However, I also have two additional pieces of paradata: how long it took each respondent to answer questions 3 and 4. This type of data is often used as an indicator of uncertainty (the longer it takes to answer, the more uncertain you are).

A simple voting model might look something like this:

```
Vote ~ 1 + Age + Gender + Leader
```

But it seems to me that this model assumes that all respondents are equally certain about their 'Vote' and 'Leader' responses. A 'Yes' vote response that took 1 second, for example, is fundamentally different to one that took 20 seconds. Where respondents are less certain, then, it seems reasonable to expect that the relationship between the variables would be weaker. But I don't think this is captured in a typical regression model.

One way that I can see to account for uncertainty in the 'Leader' variable would be to include an interaction. This is all well and good, but it doesn't help to account for uncertainty in the 'Vote' variable and, with more variables, would quickly become unwieldy.

I'd like to know how I can incorporate this uncertainty into the model above. Given the flexibility of the Bayesian framework and the premium it places on uncertainty, is it possible to include the respondents' own uncertainty of their 'Vote' and 'Leader' responses?